# trying to understand the thread safety of singleton or stateless session beans

Tags: java, ejb

To my understanding, all beans are thread safe? If I have a stateless bean, and it is called 5 times, it can either reuse the bean in the pool or create new beans, in this sense each call is a new instance. A singleton will be locked until it is free, so how is that different?

what are a few examples of when to use stateless and when to use singleton when worrying about concurrency(authentication/adding/deleting)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115533/what-is-a-real-use-case-for-stateless-over-singleton-in-ejb got a good reference from this post..

Comment: "All beans are thread safe?" No.

Comment: can you elaborate on that? I got that from stackoverflow. It was in the context of stateless beans can't have race conditions because each call will have no conversational state..If I am wrong on that I would like to know.